# + sign in R will not go away - no brackets etc missing? R STUDIO v

Tags: r

I am running a script... My script gets to this section:

```
# take the highest (in screen position) y coordinate of each fixation 
for(i in (1:nrow(EVdat))){
    EVdat$y[i] <- min(EVdat$START_Y[i], EVdat$END_Y[i])
}

# take the mean (in screen position) x coordinate of each fixation 
for(i in (1:nrow(EVdat))) {
    EVdat$x[i] <- mean(EVdat$START_X[i], EVdat$END_X[i])
}
```

and I get this:

```
>for(i in (1:nrow(EVdat))) {
+EVdat$y[i] <- min(EVdat$START_Y[i], EVdat$END_Y[i])
+}

#take the mean (in screen position) x coordinate of each fixation
```

I am not sure why it is doing this. I am not missing ANY parentheses or brackets etc? ANY help I will appreciate.
Thank you!

Comment: `EVdat$x <- 0.5*(EVdat$START_Y + EVdat$END_Y)` and `EVdat$y <- pmin(EVdat$START_Y, EVdat$END_Y)` or short `EVdat <- transform(EVdat, x=..., y=...)`

Comment: there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code in your question so it's a bit hard to diagnose ... one thing, have a look for a stray backtick (`) at the start of a line.

Comment: @jogo why the 0.5? (thanks)

Comment: thanks no (') anywhere in the line. Thanks for the suggestion though @user20650

Comment: Can you show what the console displays after the line that reads `+}`

Comment: @Gemma12 ; can you edit your question with the code in your comment ^^ please.

Comment: @Gemma12 The arithmetic mean of **a** and **b** is **(a+b)/2**. There is a function `pmin()` but there is *no* function `pmean()`. Please consult the documentation of `mean()` and `pmin()`.

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign in the console just indicates line breaks in the code, the same way the `>` indicates the start of a line. It means nothing and doesn't affect the actual execution of the code. It's just a display feature.

Comment: Try hitting `<ESC>`. It should clear the prompt line.

Comment: @RuiBarradas but it won't execute that line or code then? the Esc just cancels that prompt line and does not execute it?

Comment: No, it doesn't execute it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I need it to execute

Comment: @Gemma12 To execute a line of code press `<ENTER>` after the last character of that instruction. Like @Noah wrote, the plus sign is just a display feature.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I press CTRL+ENTER to run the line, it does not let me run anything below that line it is getting stuck on it (the red dot that tells you it is running the line just stays on and that's it)

Comment: @Gemma12 Have you tried to save the script, close RStudio and restart?

Comment: @Gemma12 Try `EVdat$y <- pmin(EVdat$START_Y, EVdat$END_Y)`. You don't need a `for` loop for this.